# Differentiating $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x^3}+\sqrt[3]{x^2}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm new to derivatives and I'm already having trouble with the exercises:

> $$\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x^3}+\sqrt[3]{x^2}$$

So, given that it's a sum of functions, I can split this in three parts, yes?

For

$$\sqrt{x}$$

I can just use one of the rules in my book:

$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$$

---

For

$$\sqrt{x^3}$$

I imagine it's the same rule:

$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x^3}}$$

---

And for the last part,

$$\sqrt[3]{x^2}$$

Once again:

$$\frac{1}{3\sqrt[3]{(x^2)^2}}$$

---

So at the end I have:

$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x^3}} + \frac{1}{3\sqrt[3]{x^4}}$$

This is wrong because the answer should be

$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}+\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{x}+\frac{2}{3\sqrt[3]{x}}$$

It seems like the second and third ones are wrong. I am wondering if I should've applied a different law.

What should I have done instead?

Comment: Use the rule $\frac{d}{dx}x^n=nx^{n-1}$, which holds for ALL real $n$. Applying it to the first term gives the desired outcome, but you should see why it doesn't also hold for the second and the third.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asked to find the derivative of the function $f(x) = x^{1/2}+x^{3/2}+x^{2/3}$.

$f'(x) = (x^{1/2})' + (x^{3/2})' + (x^{2/3})'$

Using the derivative rule for polynomial terms d/dx$(x^n)$ = $nx^{n-1}$:

$f'(x) =$ $x^{-1/2}\over 2$ + $3x^{1/2}\over 2$ + $2x^{-1/3}\over 3$

$f'(x)=$ $1\over 2\sqrt{x}$ + $3\sqrt{x}\over 2$ + $2\over 3\sqrt[3]{x}$